# pSConfig JSON is not valid. Encountered the following validation errors:

Tags: json

When I create jason file the first time it gives me some error as

Error retrieving JSON. Encountered the following error:

> garbage after JSON object, at character offset 8 (before ": {\r\n        \r\n"...") at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/JSON.pm line 171.

Then I tried to fix it and check it from the website 
When I upload it a gain it gives me

> pSConfig JSON is not valid. Encountered the following validation
>   errors:  `Node: /    Error: Properties not allowed: cck.nnu.tn,`
>   `psauhank1.ankabut.ac.ae, aub-asren-ps.aub.edu.lb,`
>   `ps.ams-van1G.kaust.edu.sa, 1ge-throughput, 185.19.231.230,`
>   `193.227.1.143, perfsonardmz.marwan.ma, ps.sc-bdc10G.kaust.edu.sa,` `perfsonar.marwan.ma.`

I don't know what is the problem and how I fixed it

the first time I missed the character but the second I don't know what is the reason
 I checked it on JSON validator

Comment: please provide more info as which tool are you using, a JSON output...

Comment: I used psconfig validate command to check the error

Comment: @ Aw Snap the configuration is for perfsonar node, its for monitoring traffic

Comment: i got now another error pSConfig JSON is not valid. Encountered the following validation errors:

   Node: /addresses/perfsonar.cnrst.ma/host
   Error: String does not match '^[a-zA-Z0-9:._\-]+$'